# log4net conflict when publishing website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, log4net

When publishing my asp.net website I get this warning:

```
No way to resolve conflict between "log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" and "log4net, 
Version=1.2.0.33710, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Choosing "log4net, 
Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" arbitrarily.
```

The point is there is not project in my solution referring Version=1.2.0.33710. Why do I get this warning?

Comment: That's odd - isn't 1.2.0.33710 nearly 15 years old? e.g. http://nvelocity-user.narkive.com/Xc2J3wpv/log4net-conflict

Comment: Yes it's odd. Are references information included in dll's similarly to the .csproj file?  Maybe there as a dll referencing log4net 1.2.0.3.

Comment: I wonder if it's worth having a look in in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

I had just come across the same issue with log4net at my work.  The issue was that there was an assembly from a projct that was built with an old log4net dependency.  This assembly was then referenced in another project/solution.

If you are referencing assemblies like this in your own project, you can use a tool like ILSpy to see what references are being using in those assemblies.

Once those assmblies have been identified, rebuild them against a newer version of log4net.